# Can you create AlwaysOn in Azure (primary) with a readable secondary replica on premises?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, azure

Is it possible to create the following setup using Always on?

> Primary replica: in Azure
>
> Secondary: readable replica on premises

I know usually people would create the opposite structure, but I couldn't find a documentation saying that this isn't possible.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: I hope you mean a readable ASYNCHRONOUS secondary.  If you mean a readable SYNCHRONOUS secondary, you may end up in a world of hurt with HADR_SYNC_COMMIT waits.

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server on Azure VMs is just regular SQL Server.  So yes, this is possible.  In fact it's not any different from having the primary on-prem and the secondary in Azure.  Once you set it up you can fail over from on-prem to Azure and back.

But you'll want to understand the differences and choose between a single AG that spans on-prem and Azure, and a Distributed AG where you have replication between an on-prem AG and an Azure AG.